# How to use exclude a category attribute in Nunit command line Execution

Tags: c#, unit-testing, jenkins, nunit, nunit-console

I Want to exclude only 1 test case parameter from the below during comman line execution

```
nunit3-console.exe Excel.Test.dll --where="cat!=IgnoreForNow"
```

but this excludes all the parameters(A, B, C, D)

```
 [TestCase("A"), Category("IgnoreForNow")]
 [TestCase("B")]
 [TestCase("C")]
 [TestCase("D")]
 public void TestReports(string fileName)
     {
         Test("foo", fileName);
     }
```

I don't want to use ignore attribute as I want to skip this test case execution in the build system but want to execute them locally.

Is there any way in NUnit while executing from command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach and command line are correct, but the way you are currently using the category attribute is incorrect.

What you currently have, is equivalent to the below in C# terms:

```cs
 [TestCase("A")]
 [TestCase("B")]
 [TestCase("C")]
 [TestCase("D")]
 [Category("IgnoreForNow")]
 public void TestReports(string fileName)
     {
         Test("foo", fileName);
     }
```

By doing this, you're applying the category to the entire `TestReports` test suite - which is why all the individual cases are excluded.

What you need to do instead, is use the `Category` property on `TestCaseAttribute`, as below:

```cs
 [TestCase("A", Category="IgnoreForNow")]
 [TestCase("B")]
 [TestCase("C")]
 [TestCase("D")]
 public void TestReports(string fileName)
     {
         Test("foo", fileName);
     }
```